# There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl

Tags: java, jaxb, glassfish, jax-ws

To deploy in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12):

> Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions There's no ObjectFactory with an
>   @XmlElementDecl for the element
>   {http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include}Include.
>           this problem is related to the following location:
>                   at protected java.util.List ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.ReferenceType.content
>                   at ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.ReferenceType
>                   at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.ObjectFactory.createReference(ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.ReferenceType)
>                   at ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.ObjectFactory
>                   at protected java.util.List ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.AppDataType.any
>                   at ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.AppDataType
>                   at protected ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.AppDataType ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.MessageDataType.appData
>                   at ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.MessageDataType
>                   at protected ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.MessageDataType
>   ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.BaseMessageType.messageData
>                   at ru.gosuslugi.smev.rev120315.BaseMessageType

Sources:

src/org/w3/_2004/_08/xop/include/Include.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2012.08.22 at 04:13:30 PM MSK 
//


package org.w3._2004._08.xop.include;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * <p>Java class for Include complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="Include">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;any namespace='##other' maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="href" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyURI" />
 *       &lt;anyAttribute namespace='##other'/>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Include", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class Include {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "href", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String href;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    /**
     * Gets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the any property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getAny().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link Object }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the href property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the href property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setHref(String value) {
        this.href = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
     * 
     * <p>
     * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
     * the value is the string value of the attribute.
     * 
     * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
     * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     always non-null
     */
    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }

}
```

org/w3/_2004/_08/xop/include/ObjectFactory.java

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2012.08.22 at 04:13:30 PM MSK 
//


package org.w3._2004._08.xop.include;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the org.w3._2004._08.xop.include package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Include_QNAME = new QName("http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include", "Include");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: org.w3._2004._08.xop.include
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Include }
     * 
     */
    public Include createInclude() {
        return new Include();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Include }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include", name = "Include")
    public JAXBElement<Include> createInclude(Include value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Include>(_Include_QNAME, Include.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you creating your `JAXBContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a JAXB model is generated from an XML schema, I always recommend creating the `JAXBContext` using the package name of the generated model.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.w3._2004._08.xop.include");
```

You don't specify what kind of application you are deploying to GlassFish, but if it is a JAX-RS/Jersey application I would recommend the use of a `ContextResolver`.  This is a standard mechanism that gives you greater control over how your `JAXBContext` is created.  Below is an example.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

@Provider
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public class SampleContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext jc;

    public SampleContextResolver() {
        try {
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.w3._2004._08.xop.include");
        } catch(JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
        if(clazz.getPackage().getName().equals("org.w3._2004._08.xop.include")) {
            return jc;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I make SOAP service. How to added JAXBContext to my SOAP service?

Comment: @AlexeySavchuk - Are you interacting with the SOAP service directly, or are you using JAXB as the default binding layer through JAX-WS?

Comment: I do not know :) I took the example jaxws-ri/samples/annotations and try to alter it to fit my needs.

Comment: If you could post your web service that would make things easier to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue 6 months ago and honestly I don't remember how it was solved (probably we didn't need some functionality so we put it aside). But today once again our lovely stacktrace cursed with the message (literally like yours)

But this time I was able to deal with it.

There's nothing wrong with Include class. But somehow, and that's my guess, it doesn't get loaded properly for jaxb, or not at the time we need it, or ... whatever.

What I was trying to do in my code is to validate a payload of the soap message.

```java
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UnifoTransferMsg.class) ;
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("UnifoTransferMsg.xsd"));

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setSchema(schema);
    marshaller.marshal(inputmsg, System.out);
```

Spare me for the hardcoded values, it's just for debugging. Nonetheless the first line is where the exception is thrown because Jaxb somehow knows nothing about Include or uses the wrong class. To fix it one needs to load multiple classes at the same call.

So the ultimate fix for me was

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Include.class, UnifoTransferMsg.class);
```

Hope that helps and maybe one day i'll expand more on the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting  @XmlRoolElement annotation on generate Include class.

Comment: This seems that your SOAP marshaller is not able to find the ObjectFactoy. I happens when we specify wrong package to marshaller (e.g. Jaxb). So, how you are consuming this web service? I mean via Spring WebServiceTemplate or something else? What are the marsheller/unmarshaller used?

Comment: It actually should be `@XmlRootElement`