# Exception - There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/cdm/foundation/parties/partyService/}

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soap, jax-rs

Trying to consume Oracle Oraganisation ERP SOAP service using java jax-rs gettting the below error

```
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/cdm/foundation/parties/partyService/}AdditionalValue3.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.partyservice.PartyPreference.additionalValue3
    at com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.partyservice.PartyPreference
    at protected java.util.List com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.OrganizationParty.partyPreference
    at com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.OrganizationParty
    at protected java.util.List com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.OrganizationPartyResult.value
    at com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.OrganizationPartyResult
    at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.ObjectFactory.createOrganizationPartyResult(com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.OrganizationPartyResult)
    at com.oracle.xmlns.apps.cdm.foundation.parties.organizationservice.ObjectFactory
```

we can able to deploy the generated as single application but when merged in my application which has consumed other erp webservice(Account,Location -which is working fine) getting the above error for oragnization soap api alone

Comment: Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282862/theres-no-objectfactory-with-an-xmlelementdecl-when-there-is-static-class
this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818117/illegalannotationexceptions-theres-no-objectfactory-with-an-xmlelementdecl-for
and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074317/theres-no-objectfactory-with-an-xmlelementdecl

Comment: Thanks for instant response. I already referred to the above link but i am not using jaxbcontext i m directly calling the soapporthttpclient class. Could you please help?